# ¿Cómo hacer un if que cumpla dos condiciones en PHP y solo muestre un resultado?

Tags: php, condiciones

Estoy realizando un if de cambios de estado pero me detengo cuando la condición cumple pero no me muestra el mensaje deseado. a continuación dejo una breve descripción.

1. Cuando el campo "Estado" esta vacío entra la primera condición
   y pinta el mensaje "Preparando el pedido"
2. Cuando capturan el campo de "Estado" y ponen el estado en "activo"
   ahora pasa el mensaje a "En camino a domicilio"
3. Ahora quiero que cambie el estado cuando capturen otro campo llamado "fecha de entrega" tendría que pintar "Entregado" pero no lo hace y se queda en el estado de "En camino a domicilio"

Mi pregunta es, ¿Cómo puedo hacer para que entre mi ifelse y cambie el estado deseado?

```
<?php  if ($row->Estado==''){
            echo  "Preparando pedido";

       } elseif ($row->Estado=='Activo'){
            echo  "En camino a domicilio";

     } elseif ($row->Estado =='Activo' && $row->Fecha==true){
            echo "Entregado";
}else{
}
?>
```

Comment: El campo `Fecha` es un boleano? Por otro lado deberias cambiar el orden de tus condiciones, primero el "entregado" y luego el "camino a domicilio"

Comment: Hola @JuanRivera, no el campo fecha es de tipo "date", como le podría hacer para que entre el ifelse y cambie el estado?

Comment: Para las comparaciones te recomiendo usar la funcion strcmp, la cual compara 2 cadenas. Es fácil de implementar. if(strcmp($var,"comparacion")==0)

Comment: @geek_root que es lo que se requiere para que imprima "Entregado". El primer valor es `Estado=='Activo'`, pero el segundo? Me dijistes que es tipo date el campo `Fecha`, entonces no puede ser `=true`. Que deberia ser?

Comment: @JuanRivera, para que imprima el estado "Entregado" tienen que estar capturados los campos de Estado y Fecha es decir: Estado: Activo Fecha= 02/03/2021, en el capo date lo puse como true para que reconozca que el valor esta capturado

Comment: @geek_root entonces la condicion deberia ser esa: `elseif ($row->Estado =='Activo' && $row->Fecha=='02/03/2021')`. Ahora para que te imprima tienes que moverlo antes del de que dice `En camino a domicilio`. Para que quede asi: Pimera condicion "preparando pedido", segunda condicion "Entregado" y tercera condicion "En camino a domicilio"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema que yo veo con tu enfoque actual es que un row que tenga como estado "Activo" y "Fecha==true" va ingresar al primer y segundo `elseif`

Entonces yo lo haria de esta manera.

```
<?php  
    if ($row->Estado==''){
        echo  "Preparando pedido";
    } elseif ($row->Estado=='Activo'){
        if($row->Fecha==true) {
            echo "Entregado";
        }
        else {
            echo  "En camino a domicilio";
        }
    }
?>
```

Tambien es bueno que evalues si puedes usar un switch - https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php

Answer (score 0):

1.- Lo que te recomiendo hacer es que le agregues un valor por defecto a tu campo fecha ejemplo: `0000-00-00` para que puedas validar si hay una fecha establecida:

```
elseif ($row->Estado =='Activo' && $row->Fecha!='000-00-00'){
  echo "Entregado";
}
```

Si no, como identificas cuando ese campo ya se halla capturado, o puedes también inicializar tu campo `fecha` como `NULL`

```
elseif ($row->Estado =='Activo' && $row->Fecha!=NULL){
      echo "Entregado";
 }
```

O bien agregar otro campo a tu tabla ejemplo `edo_pedido` con valor por defecto en `0` para los pedidos que aun NO se entregan, y cuando captures la fecha, actualizas ese campo a `1` y en vez de validar la fecha validas el `edo_pedido`

Comment: @JuanRivera Yo eh mostrado 3 posibles soluciones, como validas que el usuario a ingresado algo en tu base de datos??  bien con un **valor por defecto** o **personalizado** para que puedas detectar un cambio en tu **DB** o por su parte dejar todos los campos como **NULL**.  Te invito a leer mi respuesta detenidamente, no hay mas misterio.

Comment: @JuanRivera Y que pasará cuando la fecha cambie ?? no siempre se entregara el dia **02/03/2021** ya no entrará en esa validacion, ya han dado otra respuesta, espero que sea la que el OP busca, Saludos desde México.

Comment: @JuanRivera Lo que pasa es que en tu comentario estas dando un dato estático **02/03/2021** por eso la pregunta, al estar trabajando con Base de Datos estos valores serán dinámicos, por lo que tu validación en tu comentario no seria muy útil